# Compare Multidimensional array values using smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have multidimensional array.

```
 Array (4)
0 => Array (6)
  0 => 0
  1 => "100100105"
  2 => "honey"
  3 => "SUP"
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
1 => Array (6)
  0 => 1
  1 => "100100608"
  2 => "bunny"
  3 => "MEM"
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
2 => Array (6)
  0 => 1
  1 => "100100609"
  2 => "munny"
  3 => "DISTSTD"
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
3 => Array (6)
  0 => 2
  1 => "100300054"
  2 => "sunny"
  3 => "MEM"
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
```

Want to compare current level zero value with next level zero value like Array[0][0] == Array[1][0] using smarty.

I am able to get only the current element value. How can I get next element value in the current loop

```
  {{foreach from=$volume item=element}}
      {{if $element@iteration > 1}}
            {{$element[0]}}
          {{/if}}
  {{/foreach}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access arrays in Smarty you need to assign the index you want to access to a variable to be able to index into the array

```
{foreach from=$volume item=element name=foo}
  {assign var=nextIteration value=$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration + 1}
  {$volume[$nextIteration]}
{/foreach}
```

I guess to do the compare you would do:

```
  {foreach from=$volume item=element name=foo}
      {assign var=nextIteration value=$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration + 1}

      {if ($nextIteration + 1) >= count($volume) }
          Last element
      {elseif $volume[$nextIteration][0] == $element[0]}
          They matched!
      {else} 
          They are different!
      {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

However this is a really bad way to use Smarty as it breaks the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern in a really ugly way. You would be much better off just writing a [Smarty plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl) to handle complex situations like this. Yeah, it may still break the MVC pattern, but it's at least maintainable, instead of having complex code inside a template.